# What is a 0 "null" normal map? Or Unlit shader

Tags: shader, normal-mapping

Does anyone understand normal maps and what would color a uniformly 0 normal map be?

I'd like to convert a standard shader into an unlit shader, so (I think?) the idea is that the normal map should not contribute to the lighting.

Answer (score 1):

In the most common normal map encoding, an RGB value of (0.5,0.5,1) would be uniformly flat. If the shader is meant to be unlit, you should be able to remove anything in the code that’s using the surface normal, light / view direction, etc.

Comment: say you don't have access to modify the shader but just have to fudge it by putting textures in existing shader texture slots?

Comment: also may i ask why the B value is 1?

Comment: Because its normalised to fit in RGB range (0..1), when expanded to a normalised vector range (-1 to 1) by performing N=(colour-0.5)*2 then that RGB becomes (0,0,1) which is the default normal

Comment: @ina You usually can't magically make a normal mapping lighting shader into an unlit shader just by setting some magic normal map texture. In any case, that would require some more knowledge about how that shader works exactly beyond just that it's a "standard normal map shader".

Comment: Also in this case I am trying to convert the Unity Standard Shader to Unlit https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/shader-StandardShader.html

Comment: @ina You could try putting your unlit texture into the emissive parameter, and set the albedo/metallic/smoothness all to 0 (black). There may still be a tiny bit of Fresnel reflection on the edges, but smoothness 0 should minimize it and ensure that the lighting on the material is as close to 0 as possible.